# Upload files using angularjs without php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

just want to ask if it is possible to upload files (images, docs, pdf, etc.) using angularjs without actually using php script, instead all file uploads will use angularjs or javascript codes?. With this method i will be able to lessen the server load. Thanks

Comment: Nope AngularJS can't upload files without server side.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

*AngularJS* is solely a frontend framework. In order to upload something, you need to communicate with a server.

Comment: Patrick Reck is correct. Managing / uploading files it outside of the scope of Angular's functionality. You'll find that most front-end languages and frameworks (such as Javascript itself) don't have much support for file management. You'll need some server-side code in order to handle file uploads.

You may find additional plugins/libraries such as [ng-flow](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) useful. Plugins such as these rely other other technologies such as the HTML5 file API to manage file transfers.